# Should it be 'an' or 'a' in front of an abbreviation?

Tags: pronunciation, articles, acronyms, sandhi

I am using abbreviations for well-known phrases: e.g., "Nash equilibrium" becomes NE and "neural networks" becomes NN. Should I use "an NN" or "a NN"? Does it matter whether a reader "unfolds" the abbreviation or not when reading? That is, I think it is often the case that NE is read "Nash equilibrium", then it seems appropriate to use "a NE".

Comment: I would assume the abbreviations are read as-is letter by letter and so "an NE" and "an NN".

Comment: I'd go so far as to suggest that your choice of *a* or *an* will push your readers one way or the other; *an NE* would be read *an n e*, while *a NE* would be read *a Nash Equlibrium*.

Comment: There seems to be some debate on the issue: most sources say read it aloud (so if you'd read "en en", use "an NN", and if it's pronounced as a word (e.g. NATO) then go by how the word is pronounced ("a NATO"), but most sources also say that the rule is often not followed. https://www.aje.com/arc/editing-tip-indefinite-article-use-abbreviations/

Comment: P. S. If the reader "unfolds" the abbreviation then they can change "an" to "a" at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @StuartF, that's a great link! She gives "miRNA" (short for "microRNA") as an example which is much more complicated than my NE example since there are three common ways to read it. I was wondering whether there is a rule to be followed here, and given her discussion, this doesn't seem to be the case. I have to say that I'm quite baffled by how ambiguous the use of articles is.

Comment: @Guy They're never ambiguous. All you do is speak and it happens. Writing never matters. This is about language, not technology: even a blind illiterate always gets this right. Please read the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The  pronunciation  depends  on  the words you  Utter but  not  on  the  phrases , if  your  abbreviations  are acceptable  and understandable.

If  you  pronounce  NE  seperately ,  then it  is  an  N   E  or   or  if it is  pronounced  like  a single  word NE , It  becomes  a  NE,  if  it  is  well  established like  WHO.

NN  can be pronounced  only  seperately  so   an  NN  is  the  only option.

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates. Flag them for closure.

Comment: @ t christ.I  could  not  know  that  it  was  a duplicate.It  has just  been  identified.Thank  you  for  your  timely  suggestion.